# How to display value from db using select2

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am kinda stuck in what I am doing. I would like to select option value from db using SELECT2 but seems not to work, it keeps displaying "No results found".
Could anyone help help me, I am a learner.
**PS:** values display when I dont use select2 but I just want to give the user opportunity to type input.

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" name="select4" id="select4">
<option value="">- Choisir -</option>
<?php
$sqlpatient= "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE status='Active'";
$qsqlpatient = mysqli_query($con,$sqlpatient);
while($rspatient=mysqli_fetch_array($qsqlpatient))
{
if($rspatient[patientid] == $rsedit[patientid])
{
echo "<option value='$rspatient[patientid]' selected>$rspatient[patientid] - $rspatient[patientname]</option>";
}
else
{
echo "<option value='$rspatient[patientid]'>$rspatient[patientid] - $rspatient[patientname] $rspatient[patientfn]</option>";
}

}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: what errors you get shown in screenshoot??

Comment: How is `ajax` involved in this? This code looks like it has little to nothing to do with the "No results found" message.

Comment: '$rspatient[patientid]' => $rspatient['patientid'] ?!?!

Comment: @KUMAR, there is no errors shown, the problem is that the values that I have in option dont display

Comment: @Strawberry, what do you mean please?

Comment: _there is no errors shown_ - this cannot be true. Unless `patientid` is _actually a constant_, which seems very unlikely, then your code will not run without warnings! And you must have seen an error logged, somewhere. If you're not seeing anything on your screen, then please consult the error log.